# Looking up and selecting the correct interface implementation based on enum value in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection

Spring Boot here. I have an interface:

```
public interface AnalyticsService {
    AnalyticsResult analyze(AnalyticsRequest request);
}
```

I have dozens of different impls for this interface, each of which needs to be a `@Service`:

```
@Service
public class FizzAnalyticsService implements AnalyticsService {
    @Override
    public AnalyticsResult analyze(AnalyticsRequest request) {
        // ...
    }
}

@Service
public class BuzzAnalyticsService implements AnalyticsService {
    @Override
    public AnalyticsResult analyze(AnalyticsRequest request) {
        // ...
    }
}

// ... etc. (dozens)
```

I would like to create an `enum`, say, `AnalyticsType`:

```
public enum AnalyticsType {
    FIZZ,
    BUZZ,
    ... (dozens)
}
```

And somehow map/bind each enum value to a different `AnalyticsService` impl, such that a "client class" could select the correct impl at runtime, something like:

```
@Service
public class SomeService {

    @Autowired
    private FizzAnalyticsService fizzAnalyticsService;

    @Autowired
    private BuzzAnalyticsService buzzAnalyticsService;

    // ... etc.

    public void doSomthing(AnalyticsType type, AnalyticsRequest request) {

        AnalyticsService analyticsService = ??? (lookup by 'type')
        AnalyticsResult result = analyticsService.analyze(request);

    }

}
```

What's the appropriate solution to do this type of lookup in Spring Boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

will something like this help you? You should be able to inject all services of same type to a collection and then by some criteria filter out those which you want.

```java
public enum AnalyticsType {
    FIZZ,
    BUZZ
}

public class AnalyticsRequest {
    // data
}

public class AnalyticsResult {
    // data
}

public interface AnalyticsService {


    boolean supportsType(AnalyticsType analyticsType);

    AnalyticsResult analyze(AnalyticsRequest request);

}

@Service
public class FizzAnalyticsService implements AnalyticsService {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsType(final AnalyticsType analyticsType) {
        return AnalyticsType.FIZZ == analyticsType;
    }

    @Override
    public AnalyticsResult analyze(final AnalyticsRequest request) {
        return null;
    }
}

@Service
public class BuzzAnalyticsService implements AnalyticsService {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsType(final AnalyticsType analyticsType) {
        return AnalyticsType.BUZZ == analyticsType;
    }

    @Override
    public AnalyticsResult analyze(final AnalyticsRequest request) {
        return null;
    }
}


@Service
public class SomeService {

    private final List<AnalyticsService> analyticsServices;

    public SomeService(final List<AnalyticsService> analyticsServices) {
        this.analyticsServices = analyticsServices;
    }

    public void doSomthing(AnalyticsType type, AnalyticsRequest request) {

        AnalyticsService analyticsService = analyticsServices.stream()
                .filter(as -> as.supportsType(type))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Type %s doesn't support analytics".formatted(type)))
        AnalyticsResult result = analyticsService.analyze(request);

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @bilak this is definitely a working solution but I was hoping Spring might have some fancy annotations or utils classes for accomplishing this sort of thing. Maybe something like JPA's `@Discriminator` annotation, or something similar. I'll keep this question open for a few days and if no one else chimes in with a more "Spring-esque" solution, I'll happily give your answer the green check! Thanks again

Comment: afaik there is nothing from spring. This is strategy pattern and it can be enhanced with factory which will hold all of  `AnalyticsService`s and return only those which you request (part of `doSomething` method).